# Displaying OMDB Api JSON data in html

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax

I am trying to integrate OMDB API to my movie's list. There is simple bash script that generate CSV file with all movies in specified directory. I thought that might be good if I will add feature to get movie info from OMDB API.
So I'm trying to load JSON data after clicking on movie. The problem is that I don't know how to display movie data in proper way.
I'm just begining to code in JS, thanks in advance for any advices.

Here the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>List</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        $('.link').click(function(){
          var page=$(this).attr('rel')

          $('#display').load(page);
          console.log(page)
        });
      })
    </script>
    <div class="container">


      <h1>List</h1>
      <div id="display">
        movie info
      </div>
      <br />
      <hr />
      <br />
      <ul>
        <?php

        //Open the file.
        $fileHandle = fopen("list.csv", "r");

        //Loop through the CSV rows.
        while (($row = fgetcsv($fileHandle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            echo '<li class="link" rel="http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=' . $row[1] . '&y=' . $row[2] . '&plot=short&r=json">' . $row[0] . '</li><br />';
        }
        ?>
      </ul>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can read up on how to [ask] a question and create a [mcve]. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
var api_key = "YOU OMDB API KEY";
var film = $("#idIMDB").text(); //GET TEXT FROM DOM, THIS CONTENTS IMDB ID EX: tt6320628
$.getJSON("http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=" +
    escape(film) +
    "&apikey=" +
    api_key,
    function(json) {
        //RottenTomatoes
        var rottentomatoes = json.Ratings[1].Value;
            $('#RT').html(rottentomatoes); // ADD VALUE DOM ID #RT
    });
return arguments.callee;

});
```

Only example get value rotten-tomatoes rating, but with your imagination search and find anything in the JSON response from OMDB.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you load [csv to javascript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson) object and create list of links with some library for example [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/), and next create component to showing data about selected movie.